# How to set LOCALE in Windows console

Tags: windows, maven, locale, surefire

I need to set locale for a single console. I want to build Apache Wicket framework (Maven-based build), but it fails on test which relies on en_US locale. 
I don't want to skip tests.
I don't want to skip the particular failing tests.

Is it possible? Or is changing the system-wide locale the only way?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing Wicket specific and I have not done this myself. But, a little bit of google led me to this:
[Re: maven-surefire-plugin and default locale](http://www.mail-archive.com/users@maven.apache.org/msg98949.html) which again leads to [Surefire Plugin Using System Properties](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html).

Hope that helps

Comment: Bingo. sysprop `user.region` - The two-letter country code of the default locale. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for this, showed up [this link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sr-Latn-CS/ITCG/thread/cda51fac-455b-4222-9922-d584e10a7bf6), which talks about creating an xml file and invoking it from a batch file as described in [this link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721887%28WS.10%29.aspx).

Comment: Thx but this seems to be related to some Windows specific GUI descriptors.