# How to change the console output into English on Hungarian system

Tags: windows, console

Windows vista with Hungarian.
I want to change the console output into English.
'chcp 437' is no use, the output is still in Hungarian.

Any other method for this?

for example, I want to get the volume info via batch file.

```
chcp 437
echo list volume >list.txt
diskpart /s list.txt > result.txt
```

Now, I want the content of result.txt is in English, but it is still in Hungarian.

Comment: You change changed the codepage in `Control Panel → Regional and Language Options → Advanced → Language for non-Unicode programs (combobox)`?

Comment: Please, describe in more details: (1) what program is failing (2) what is displayed to output (3) what do you expect it should display. Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590981/how-to-set-locale-in-windows-console/4591166#4591166) will help.

Comment: why is this tagged hungarian-notation?!

Comment: Sorry, I just want to tag as hungarian. Delete it.

Comment: It looks like `chcp` does not change the codepage really. I've tried the following: `cp 866` (Cyrillic codepage for MS-DOS) and still e.g. `time` speaks English to me. Well, I believed that build-in CMD functions like `time`/`date` should speak different languages, but that is not true for WinXP. But for `diskpart` I can definitely say, that this utility can only speak one language: I have extracted all strings from it (and all messages turned out to be in English), and it does note load the external resources. So look for English `diskpart` from English WinXP (I can send you one).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that the program does not read the Windows locale setting (which is English for unicode) and starts displaying the messages in Hungarian while you have switched the console to English (e.g. there are no glyphs for Hungarian characters). I am not sure if the program you are using can speak English at all.

Comment: I use the build-in function, which is BAT and diskpart command.